# What's the correct way to store class instance (e.g. MKMapItem) in core data? (swiftUI)

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui, ios14

**Short version**

How could I store the value of class instance(for example: [MKMapItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem)) into core data?

**Long version:**

I need to present/store following info after the user select location:

```
   * <MKMapItem>.name: String
   * <MKMapItem>.placemark.title: String
   * <MKMapItem>.placemark.coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

1. In the beginning, I plan to store coordinate, and read other info by
   `MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)`.  Unfortunately it has never
   been able to find `placemark` from `coordinate`.
2. Thus, I change my plan to store the whole `MKMapItem` instance. I
   supposed I can use JSON to encode and store as Binary Data.
   However, in such way, I need to duplicate the whole `MKMapItem`
   structure and conform each to `Codable`.

*Thus I wonder if there is a better way to store it ?*

3. My backup plan is to create an entity to store `name:String, title:String, latitude:Double, longitude: Double` in CoreData, but
   then I lost the MKMapItem class structure.

But I feel there might be a much better way to do it...

p.s. I started learning iOS Dev from SwiftUI time. Thus I do not have much pre-knowledge for codes in MVC times or earlier.

Comment: You can't persist an arbitrary object in Core Data.  You need to store sufficient information to let you recover the place mark from the map kit api. Place marks are potentially transient objects.  A given geographic place, such as a business, may be at an address for months or years.

Comment: Go with the third option .. just store name, title, long and lat.. what's the issue with that?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for pointing out transient issue. That's true, so I shouldn't do anything like option2.

Comment: In case any future visitor share the same frustration as me in option 1:  MKPlacemark(coord...) would return an mkplacemark object but that one wouldn't contain the info like address..Here seems a better way to reverse: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/converting_between_coordinates_and_user-friendly_place_names

Comment: @davidev I supposed that, if I could save a MKMapItem, I could keep more info if I need for future. But as Paulw11 has pointed out, it's not much value to save transient info permanently.